# how to add labels to the markers in different curves in the same graph

Tags: matlab, label, markers

I have written a MATLAB .code to plot multiple curves with different markers on the same graph. Now I need to add a list of the labels to the different markers I have used. Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the [`legend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) command.

For example in the doc:

```
figure
x = -pi:pi/20:pi;
plot(x,cos(x),'-ro',x,sin(x),'-.b')
hleg1 = legend('cos_x','sin_x');
```

Will give you this:

[image]

Hope this helps!